# split arrays into uneven groups

Tags: python, list, split

In python given an array like so:

```
a = [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14 ]
```

I would like to split this into three uneven groups, such that I end up with something like this:

```
b = [0, 1, 3, 4]
c = [6, 7, 8]
d = [10, 14]
```

I want to group numbers by multiples of 5. So any integers from 0 - 4 would end up in the first array, 5 - 9 in the second, and so on.

Comment: How do you specify how long you want `b` and `c` to be?  In other words, what properties do you want the unevenness to have?

Comment: Chunks of a maximum of 5, yes.

Answer (score 3):

[Itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is always the answer!

Here we round each number down to the nearest 5, and then group by equal numbers:

```
>>> for n, g in itertools.groupby(a, lambda x: round(x/5)*5):
    print list(g)

[0, 1, 3, 4]
[6, 7, 8]
[10, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can be more or less time efficient if we know something about the numbers we're working with.  We could also come up with a very quick one that's terribly memory inefficient, but consider this, if it fits your purposes:

```
#something to store our new lists in
range = 5 #you said bounds of 5, right?
s = [ [] ]
for number in a:
    foundit = false
    for list in s:
        #deal with first number
        if len( list ) == 0:
            list.append( number )
        else:
            #if our number is within the same range as the other number, add it
            if list[0] / range == number / range:
                foundit = true
                list.append( number )
    if foundit == false:
       s.append( [ number ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand your definition of groups better, I think this relatively simple answer will not only work, it should also be very fast:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14]
chunk_size = 5
buckets = defaultdict(list)

for n in a:
    buckets[n/chunk_size].append(n)

for bucket,values in sorted(buckets.iteritems()):
    print '{}: {}'.format(bucket, values)
```

Output:

```
0: [0, 1, 3, 4]
1: [6, 7, 8]
2: [10, 14]
```

Comment: To further explain my example a bit let me explain what the end result is.  Currently I am querying our monitoring system for time series data so I can craft a report.  If I query for 1 hour of data for example, I want to split that up into 5 min chunks, all times are returned in epoc. Because it comes from our monitoring system there may be gaps in the timestamps, a machine failed for example so data was unavailable for that period of time.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, in that case see my revised answer.